# jupyter nbconvert: How to execute and output multiple format without execute multiple time?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I am using [nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

From the SimpleNotebook.ipynb, I want to output two file:

- Execute SimpleNotebook.ipynb, then save the notebook with output cell.
- A HTML without code.

My command line for doing the job:

```
jupyter nbconvert SimpleNotebook.ipynb --to notebook --execute 
jupyter nbconvert SimpleNotebook.ipynb --to html --execute --no-input
```

output console

```
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook SimpleNotebook.ipynb to notebook
[NbConvertApp] Executing notebook with kernel: python3
[NbConvertApp] Writing 18547 bytes to SimpleNotebook.nbconvert.ipynb
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook SimpleNotebook.ipynb to html
[NbConvertApp] Executing notebook with kernel: python3
[NbConvertApp] Writing 280188 bytes to SimpleNotebook.html
```

It created

- SimpleNotebook.nbconvert.ipynb (a notebook with output cell)
- SimpleNotebook.html (the web output)

jupyter nbconvert SimpleNotebook.ipynb --to notebook --execute --no-input
jupyter nbconvert SimpleNotebook.ipynb --to html --execute --no-input

The problem: It run twice. As I can see in the console output:

```
[NbConvertApp] Executing notebook with kernel: python3
```

Happen twice, because it execute notebook again for each command line.

I would like to **output both file** SimpleNotebook.nbconvert.ipynb and SimpleNotebook.html but only **execute the notebook once**. How should I write the command line ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want `--execute` in your second command. And make sure to use the output of the first command as the input for the second.

The following would replace your two commands using your example:

```py
jupyter nbconvert SimpleNotebook.ipynb --to notebook --execute 
jupyter nbconvert SimpleNotebook.nbconvert.ipynb --to html --no-input
```